# Python - Slice Dataframe in several smaller dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 3000 rows, sorted by date, and 5 columns.

I need to slice this dataframe in several ones, of 251 days, using a loop. So the first one will have from day 1 to day 251, the 2nd one from day 2 to 252, and so on.

Then, I want to save it, so then I can iterate a function over it.

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

[SOLVED]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of these dataframes this way:

```
step = 250
dataframe_list = [dataframe[i:i + step] for i in range(len(dataframe) - step)]
```

if you want to use this in a loop only once, you can use a generator to use less memory.

```
dataframe_generator = (dataframe[i:i + step] for i in range(len(dataframe) - step))
```

Comment: Hi @Axel, 
Thank you for your help. 



I tried your suggestion, but it happens to create list from row 1 to 249 and then from 250 to 499, instead of 1 to 249, 2 to 250, 3 to 251 and so on. Here's what I wrote with your suggestion:           



step = 250
prices_list = [prices[i:i + step] for i in range(0, len(prices), step)]

Comment: Oh sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thank you. 

Is there any way to refer directly to, for instance, the 45th iteration?

Comment: With the first solution, of course: `dataframe_list[45]`, but with the generator, it is not possible (or you have to do a loop with the `next` function, very inefficient). If you need it, you can just write `dataframe[45:45 + step]`